# getting error org.json.JSONException: Value <pre of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I want to access my Android apps through Web-Service.
but getting error in my android app ,

i am using volley & POST method for login.. `public class Main extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    public static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.54.103.8:4067/evivaservices/Webservices/login";

```
public static final String KEY_USERNAME="username";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD="password";

private EditText editTextUsername;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private Button buttonLogin;

private String username;
private String password;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);

    editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username1);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password1);

    buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
}
private void userLogin() {
    username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        Next();
                    }
                    catch(JSONException e)
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            map.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
            map.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
            return map;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void Next(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeScreen.class);
    intent.putExtra(KEY_USERNAME, username);
    startActivity(intent);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
userLogin();
}
```

}
`

```
JSON DATA


{
  "id": 31,
  "username": "andrew.cope@services.co.in",
  "user_image": "http:\/\/103.54.103.8:4067\/evivaservices\/img\/profile_31.png",
  "err-code": 0
}
```

`

Comment: You should use `JsonRequest` instead of `StringRequest`.

Comment: Your code should not compile in first instance, as you are missing a `;`. To solve your issue,  remove the line `JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("err-code")`

Comment: @chandeshwar Thakur : Did that solve your problem?

Comment: yes bro...i solved .this.by JsonObjectRequest method..thanx for suggest me...but i dont know why my reputation decreased

Comment: @chandeshwar Thakur: That is because someone downvoted your question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your `StringRequest` to `JsonRequest` as below:

```
 JsonRequest jsonRequest = new JsonRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL, new Response.Listener<>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Object response) {
            try {
                Next();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
            map.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
            return map;
        }

        @Override
        protected Response parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object another) {
            return 0;
        }
    };
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Hello dear you made a mistake while you parsing the response

```
 JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("err-code")
```

remove above the line and then parse again.

Answer (score 0):

In you JSON DATA, I not find array, so you shouldn't use JsonArray, you can delete this line in your code :`JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("err-code").`

Comment: check it code properly...getting error at JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

Comment: Please explain *why* this fixes the problem

Comment: @AesSedai101 JSONArray is used for JSON data has this snipped like  "result" : [ {"value1": 1} , {"value2":2} , {"value3":3} ]. you konw JSON data has array. In this case, you must use JSONArray class.